# Capybara - how to check for text on submit button?

Tags: css, selenium, capybara

I have a submit button with text and I want to check for both.

i.e. the actual page has:

```
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Continue" tabindex="3"
name="nav[save]"></input>`
```

So I've tried

```
  it "I can see the Continue button" do
    expect(page.find('input[type="submit"]').find('input[value="Continue"]')).to be
  end
```

but I get

```
Unable to find css "input[value=\"Continue\"]"
```

and

```
expect(page.find('input[type="submit"]')).
  to have_selector('input[value="Continue"]')
```

but I get

```
expected to find css "input[value=\"Continue\"]" but there were no matches
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for both you can do it in single css selector like

```
input[type=\"submit\"][value=\"Continue\"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution that works with your view:

```
expect(find('.button').value).to eq 'Continue'
```

In the console:

```
[1] pry(#<Cucumber::Rails::World>)> expect(find('.button').value).to eq 'Continue'
=> true
```